# What is a muslim prayer curtain?

Tags: salat

I am not a muslim but I just hope I could get some information here. There is a meme circulating online that president Barack Obama has held a prayer curtain in the White House:

[image: Obama in front of a Muslim Prayer Curtain]

Regardless if this is true or not. What is a muslism prayer curtain?

Comment: Related: http://www.snopes.com/politics/obama/photos/ovaloffice.asp; in particular, fwiw, *"There is no such thing as a "Muslim prayer curtain," and the patterned drapes shown behind President Obama bear no "Arabic symbols" or other markings of significance. They're simply gold silk lampas curtains that have adorned a wall in the East Room of the White House (a site commonly used for presidential press conferences) through several presidential administrations since the early 1960s."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any sort of idol worship is not allowed in Islam. A "prayer curtain" would fall under the same category. All that is required for prayer is wudu (washing oneself before prayer) and a clean place.

Comment: A source would certainly make this better. +1 in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a "Muslim prayer curtain". But some people will believe anything.

Answer (score 2):

There is Islamic prayer rug or sajadah such as this: [http://www.amazon.com/Islamic-Prayer-Rug-Muslim-Sajadah/dp/B00MIH4OMS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MIH4OMS)

But prayer curtain?? That thing surely does not exist.